# builtins.ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy, int, boolean

So at the end of this AI project I'm getting this error that I think is **numpy** related.

```
trace[2] = np.nonzero(np.random.multinomial( 8, self.P[x,a,:]))[0][0]

def traces2Q(self, trace):
    for tr_line in trace:
        s=int(tr_line[0])
        a=int(tr_line[1])
        self.Q[s][a] = self.Q[s][a] + tr_line[3] + self.gamma*max(self.Q[trace[2].astype(int),:]) - self.Q[s][a]
```

As you can see, I've tried to convert the array **trace[2]** to type int, which got me this error message. The error message comes from **max(self.Q[trace[2].astype(int),:])**, where **trace[2]** is defined beforehand in another function.

Comment: Well, what *is* the value of `trace[2]`?  The Python interpreter seems to think it's a numpy vector, which cannot be directly converted to an `int`.  Perform a little basic debugging to see where you've departed from your expected data flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from you using the built-in `max` on a `np.ndarray` object, it implicitly calls the comparisons on the elements of the array, in this case, giving you "rows" of numpy arrays, hence the error. Use the `.max` built-in method for `numpy.ndarray` objects, or use `numpy.max` instead of the built-in `max`

So change:

```
self.gamma*max(self.Q[trace[2].astype(int),:])
```

To:

```
self.gamma*np.max(self.Q[trace[2].astype(int),:])
```